# How to reduce babel-polyfill size (150 KB minified)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-polyfill

I just setup new webpack 4 project and in my main js file imported babel-polyfill

`import 'babel-polyfill';`

And after webpack production build i analized my bandle with `source-map-explorer` i see such picture [image]

So babel-polyfill (core-js) took **150 Kb** which is too much IMO.

Any thoughts how can i reduce size ? I don't want to include any specific polyfills (there should be some tree-shaking, so not used code should be deleted ?).

I use this boilerplate: https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate/tree/master/config

Comment: @JaromandaX, none. But according to comments from github it should be ~60-80 Kb minified. And in my case i see x2 size and this is strange. Don't you think ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that - sorry

Answer (score 5):

The size of **150kb** seems reasonable to me because you're importing all polyfills. Therefore the tree-shaking feature of webpack4 will not remove any unused code because everything is used.

*I might assume the sources claiming the size for the whole bundle should be ~60-80kb meant the size after minification + compression.*

Did you read the [**instructions**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) of how to use the `@babel/polyfill` library correctly? It [**recommends**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#size) the usage of [**@babel/preset-env**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) to import only the polyfills you need for your production target. This will probably greatly reduce the size of your bundle.

Comment: You wrote: *"Therefore the tree-shaking feature of webpack4 will not remove any unused code because everything is used."*  It  can be understand different wayt, but generally, do we have any third party tool that can check that "everything is used in the bandle"?

Comment: you don't need to check... it runs the code so it needs it: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-polyfill/src/index.js webpack will absolutely include anything ran with "import 'abc'"

Comment: The tree-shaking feature does check your bundle for unused code and removes it, but in this case, everything from the polyfill library is used, because everything is imported. As i wrote @babel/preset-env helps you to not import polyfills that are not needed for your target environment.

Comment: OK. It seems I got it. "Not used" means "not imported". But I do not understand why transpiler can't report which polyfills where not used since he definitely knows which were used (during transpilation phase). Or Babel can do it?